# Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

Here is my code. the output should be 32.9. But it seems showing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   ArrayLocation.main(ArrayLocation.java:14)

---

```
public class ArrayLocation {
    private double coords[];

    public ArrayLocation(double[] coods){
        this.coords=coords;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] coords={5.0,0.0};
        ArrayLocation accra= new ArrayLocation(coords);
        coords[0]=32.9;
        coords[1]=-117.2;
        System.out.println(accra.coords[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.coords=coords;` -> Check this line... That's why you should use an IDE and give attention to warnings too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code.

Change

```
public ArrayLocation(double[] coods) {
```

to

```
public ArrayLocation(double[] coords) {
```

Comment: OMG !!!! i did a stupid mistake.   thanks!!